# How I can restart app when user close it?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-service

I need to reopen my app under certain conditions when user try to close it or forbid him to do it.
I try use foreground service for this case, but it is not able to start activity from service in Android 10.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean prevent them from backing out of it, or do you mean to reopen it when they force close it in the task switcher?

Comment: For this to be possible, your app needs at least to be a system app. Imagine a world where you download an app from play store, and instantly get locked into it, this would  basically be a ransomware framework, dont you think?

Comment: i mean reopen it when they force close it in the task switcher